# Hair Particles interaction with wind

Tags: particles, baking, force-fields

I use wind as a force but as after baking i saw
The wind just blew  away my hair particles from the mesh
How to solve the issue

Comment: Where did the rest of the question go

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - please check this out before asking anything in this community. Depending on your question you must provide images or videos or the blend file to specify your question. That way we will be able to provide maximum help. Thank U :)

Answer (score 2):

Blender's particle system is complex with the excuse that its powerful, there are a lot of settings and want it or not you have to configure everything correctly otherwise it will act unexpected. If you post a picture of all the particle settings I may be able to help you. If not then its probably a setting that you have missed or misconfigured it should be pinned to its origin be default though, except if the wind is affecting a rigidbody and not a particle system.